# Error during importing categories ids with skus in magmi Magento

Tags: magento, csv, runtime-error, magmi

Hi i have a csv in which there are two columns  sku and category_ids
and have a values like

```
"sku"   "category_ids"
"3751"  "416"
"3752"  "452"
"3753"  "452"
"3754"  "452"
"3755"  "452"
"3756"  "452"
"3757"  "452"
"3758"  "513"
"3759"  "417"
"3760"  "453"
"3761"  "514"
"3762"  "514"
"3763"  "514"
"3764"  "514"
"3765"  "417"
"3766"  "451"
"3767"  "451"
"3768"  "451"
```

but when i am running profile in magmi it gives a  errors like

```
 No sku info found for record #1
No sku info found for record #2
No sku info found for record #3
No sku info found for record #4
No sku info found for record #5
No sku info found for record #6
No sku info found for record #7
No sku info found for record #8
No sku info found for record #9
No sku info found for record #10
```

I have all these skus in the admin mentioned in the csv.
so please suggest me how can i fix this. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please check your csv seperator, what you are using in csv file and what you have configured in magmi. I guess its `tab` in csv file, check if its same in magmi.